# how to solve WARNING: Illegal character in path at index 23

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, spring-security, primefaces

i got error when i'm running my application

im using :

jsf 2.0 
springframework 3.0.2 
primefaces 3.1.1 
glassfish server 3.0.1

this my error :

```
WARNING: Illegal character in path at index 23: file:/D:/Project/Secret Project/Hobic Project EE/Hobic/dist/gfdeploy/Hobic/Hobic-war_war/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 23: file:/D:/Project/Secret Project/Hobic Project EE/Hobic/dist/gfdeploy/Hobic/Hobic-war_war/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

anyone help me, for solve this problem
thx agungdmt

Comment: Sounds like you have an illegal character in path at index 23.

Comment: @Sparky You must be a descendant of Sherlock Holmes!

Comment: @MattHandy, the quality of the comment simply reflects the quality of the question.

Comment: hahaha thx for your response, it's really funny..:D holmes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a warning not an error. Counting the characters in path leads to the space in *Secret Project*.  Remove all spaces from the path and the warning should go away.